# how to actually make an auction functionality into my daap?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask, daap

I've been trying to make an NFT marketplace with the functionality of auctioning an item. But I don't know how to achieve this via **signing transaction**.
I have tried to use almost every method of **signing** from web3.js, but it requires the **private key** of the user.
However there's the function `web3.eth.signTransaction` which doesn't require any private key to sign the transaction, but it gives an error on the console. saying : `Error: The method 'eth_signTransaction' does not exist / is not available`.
Can someone give me an overview of how this signing and sending transaction can be done implementing the functionality of auctioning an nft like nft marketplaces: opensea or foundation.

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html#signtransaction):

> *Signs a transaction. This account needs to be unlocked.*

It doesn't require the private key, but it requires the account (that is used for signing the transaction) to be unlocked on the node. Which means the node needs to hold the private key to unlock the account.

It's usually allowed on local nodes such as Ganache or private nodes.

And public nodes such as Infura usually disable this functionality (hence the error message "`eth_signTransaction` is not available") since they don't store your private keys.

---

You can ask the user to sign the transaction using their wallet. For example using MetaMask (or any other wallet implementing the [Ethereum provider API](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/sending-transactions.html)):

```
const transactionParameters = {
  from: ethereum.selectedAddress, // must match user's active address
  to: 'your address'
};

await ethereum.request({
  method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
  params: [transactionParameters],
});
```

Comment: The above function actually executes the transaction, but I want to sign it for later use. Are there any other methods of doing that?